# delphi comboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

how does one get the picked value of a combo box from delphi 7

lets say it has items, how does one know which row (item) was picked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find the selected item with:

```
combobox.ItemIndex; // -1 if none
```

You can get the value using

```
combobox.Items[combobox.ItemIndex]
```

Comment: obviously you get an error if you write combobox.Items[combobox.ItemIndex] without checking that combobox.ItemIndex<>-1 first

Answer (score 4):

combobox.text will hold the value which was selected

Comment: One issue here however is if the combobox allows editing the text may not match any of the items, which is worth noting.

Answer (score -2):

When you want to use combobox.text, i recommend to set style to csDropDownList and ItemIndex to 0 in object inspector to have combobox initialized.

Comment: since i have no enough points to comment previous answer i needed to put it as separate answer. Toby's comment actually warns about same thing.